# Run job after trigger - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to run a job after a trigger each time a column changes (for each row in the table), I would like to run a job.

The job should wait for 5 minutes and then run a stored procedure. I have made something, but when running it, it looks like the whole database is being locked, and I don't want the database to be locked while there are thousand of requests at the same time.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterUPDATETrigger 
ON [TmpTable]
FOR UPDATE 
AS
  DECLARE @EmpID INT, @EmpName VARCHAR(50),

  SELECT @EmpID = ID FROM foo ;
  SELECT @EmpName = Name FROM foo ;

  IF UPDATE(TimeSpan)
  BEGIN
    EXEC io_sp_delete_reservation @EmpID
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00.000';
  END
```

Comment: You're waiting for 5mins inside a trigger, so the transaction doing the update is locked for that 5mins, therefore locking the table. You can't put a wait inside a trigger, you need to add a job to a queue and process it elsewhere.

Comment: ok got it. would you please help me with an answer of how it should look like?
what does it mean "job to a queue and process it .."?

Comment: I mean, I know how to create job, but I need to run the job each time it's being triggered

Comment: Thats too broad a question for here I'm afraid, some kind of scheduled service - SQL Server does have that built in with the SQL Server agent. Otherwise a windows service. Or Window scheduled task...

Answer (score 0):

Kinda late to answear, but it might help someone.

I was having the same problem, in which I needed to wait for a certain time to trigger an action to the database, and solved with the following:

1 - Create a new job in `SQL Server Agent > Jobs > New Job`

2 - Define the first step as the wait for the execution, as in:

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00.000';
```

3 - Define the second step as the execution of the procedure itself, as in:

```
EXEC io_sp_delete_reservation @EmpID
```

4 - Inside the trigger, call the procedure `sp_start_job` with the name of the created job:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'My awaiting job'
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16